# Screws for macbook pro early 2011 fan

Tags: hardware

when I was cleaning my mac book's fans I destroyed one screw head shown in picture (right fan) [image] picture from ifixit

How can I replace it?
Drill that screw up, or other method?
And where can I buy a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fan screws are most likely 7.2 mm or 5.3 mm T6 Torx screws (the appropriate iFixit teardown will help you)

If the body of the screw is still screwed in, it could be very difficult to remove and require more specialist repair.

Comment: The screw head it is damaged, what do thou think about drill it? Oh yea i found this page http://www.powerbookmedic.com/xcart1/_search.php?q=screws&sort=0&page=1 but i don't know which screw to buy

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't fancy drilling it as you'll probably destroy the hole in the process. For larger screws, the usual process is to weld another screw onto it and unscrew that, but I'm not sure that would be easy with a tiny screw. I'd probably try unscrewing it with needle nose pliers first. The screw is probably one of [these](http://www.impactcomputers.com/922-8646.html) but you'd be best contacting their customer service to check as it's slightly shorter than iFixit described.

Comment: Thank you, I tried forceps in I pul it out. Now I'm going to order screws. Thank you